# Python iterate through rows in a DataFrame and post XML values to an API

Tags: python, xml, pandas, iterator, python-requests

POST UPDATED WITH CORRECTED CODE. I have a simple http POST request that takes some short XML, however there are hundreds of individual requests that need to be posted regularly, so a for loop seems like a good option.  Based on the comment below, I see that i originally had a bad loop so I have updated the code with a working one.  I'm sure that this isn't the most efficient way to do this, but it is working.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    name = row['name']
    value = row['lengthValue']
    postalCode = row['postalCode']
    address = row['address']
    state = row['state']
    country = row['country']
    xml = """<root>
    <name>{0}/name>
    <isNew>yes</isNew>
    <length option="true" units="feet">
        <value>{1}</value>
    </length>
    <address postalCode="{2}" address1="{3}" state="{4}" country="{5}"/>
    </root>""".format(name, value, postalCode, address, state, country)
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'}
    response= requests.post('https://some.url/id/%i/addnew' % uid, data=xml, headers=headers)
```

Note that there is also a variable in the url, which is an integer from the uid variable defined by a different function which gets the specific ID of the account that these new values are being posted to.

The sample dataframe is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['A','B','C'], 
'lengthValue':[34, 56, 23], 
'postalCode':[20001,30001,40001], 
'address':['123 Main St', '321 Front Street', '100 First Ave'], 
'state':['ME', 'OR', 'FL'], 
'country':['US', 'US', 'US']})
```

Comment: what's your question? why do you `return` from a `for` loop? Why do you define `headers` and make the post outside the `for`?

Comment: The code was showing up incorrectly, the post is inside the for, but it it isn't working.  Upon inspection, the enumerate function doesn't seem to be inserting the values in the statement and posting to the url.

Comment: Please edit your post to include a question. Why do you `return` from a `for` loop?

Answer (score 0):

I think you got a wrong idea about what the `enumerate` [built-in](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) actually does.

Simply put, on each iteration of the `for` loop, `i` will get values from {0, 1, 2, ...} and `col_name` will get the items of `df.index`.

You can inspect this by running:

```
for i, col_name in enumerate(df.index):
    print 'i ->', i
    print 'col_name ->', col_name
    print '------' # just a loop separator
```

Then you will have to re-think how to form your `xml` string. Im **guessing** you get `IndexError` because `.format` cant find element `2`.

My answer can not fully solve your problem because I don't know what your variables are storing. In particular, I don't see where `row` comes from. But shuolud point where the problem lies and how to work from there.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, this actually allowed me to create a correct loop, which I have updated above. Really appreciate it @marcos

Comment: Great! Now that the for loop "works" and you get your `xml` string properly defined / formatted, does your code as a whole work?